# How to verify server certificate on Android4?

Tags: android, certificate

I want to connect to a private server. I can get the server's certificate. How I verify the server's certificate using certificates installed on Android which include the system certifcate and certificates installed by my apk?

Comment: The url http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html may be helpful. It provides the sample code.